# Will installing CM9 on Xperia PLAY, lose its Playstation power?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

I want to know that if I install CM9 on my Xperia PLAY will it lose its ability to play Playstation games or the games which uses D-pad controls & X,O controls?
How will it affect performance? What are the advantages and disadvantages of CM9 on Xperia PLAY?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1846274) suggests that the proximity sensor and touchpads currently don't work with CM9.  this may be fixed in a later release, but I'd hold off for the moment.